Changing a dbt model materialization in production
In dbt, if a model was initially deployed as a view in production, and in the next version of your dbt project, your team decides to change it to a table, what is the proper way to deploy the project to avoid getting an error during dbt run?

I don't think there should be a problem. You can simply change the materialization from the view to the table, merge the changes into your production git brunch, and on the next dbt run dbt will create a table in your database so all dependent models will reference this table instead of a view.
Keep in mind that view will still exist in your database, so if you want to keep it clean, you will need to manually drop it.
Please clarify if you have any specific concern about changing the materialization.

I am getting an error when I changed the materialization from view to table:
00:44:37    Database Error in model staging_test (models\staging_test.sql)   ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot use DROP TABLE with 'dbo.staging_test__dbt_backup' because 'dbo.staging_test__dbt_backup' is a view. Use DROP VIEW. (3705) (SQLMoreResults)")   compiled Code at target\run\dbt_test\models\staging_test.sql
I am using  dbt=1.7.17 and sqlserver=1.7.4

Have you tried dbt run --full-refresh?

Also, keep in mind materializing as a table would take some time to process depending on the size of the data, as compare to view. So, make sure you manage pipeline execution accordingly.
